# Como crear una función que incluya la moda de una tabla

Tags: r, rstudio

He intentado crear una función que me genere un resultado en cada uno de los vectores , pero al añadirle la función "moda", me da error. La función queda así.

```
moda <- function(x) {
   return(as.numeric(names(max(table(x)))))
}
info_variable <- function(vector) {
  print(paste("Tipo de modo:",mode(vector)))
  print("Niveles de la variable:")
  print(head(levels(as.factor(vector))))
  if (mode(vector) == "numeric") {
    print("Resumen estadístico:")
    print(summary(vector))
    print("Moda del vector")
    print(moda(x)) 
    print(paste("Desviación estándar:",round(sd(vector),4)))}
  else print("Variable categórica o con carácteres")
} ## ERROR: Error in table(x) : objeto 'x' no encontrado
```

Sin el print(moda(x)) queda así con un vector del df que manejo.

```
## [1] "Tipo de modo: numeric"
## [1] "Niveles de la variable:"
## [1] "0" "1"
## [1] "Resumen estadístico:"
##    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
##  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.2133  0.0000  1.0000 
## [1] "Desviación estándar: 0.4099"
```

Comment: Es que `x` no existe en el contextp de `info_variable`, ¿no debería ser en todo caso  `print(moda(vector))`?

Comment: Voy a probar, muchas gracias!